# NullPointerException on Adapter.<init> in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I'm getting this error frequently from my published app. The app crashes in the adapter constructor in the line where i initialize my ArrayList.

The app runs perfectly on emulators and devices that i use so i have no idea whats causing it.

Error Log

> Stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at java.util.ArrayList.<init> (ArrayList.java:191)
  **at com.nullbytesoftware.myapplication.Adapter.<init> (Adapter.java:24)
  at com.nullbytesoftware.myapplication.Emotes.CreateViews (Emotes.java:273)
  at com.nullbytesoftware.myapplication.Emotes.onCreate (Emotes.java:94)**
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7032)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7023)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1236)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2821)
```

**Where i create my recyclerview**

```java
private void CreateViews( ArrayList<Emote> arr) {
    //arr is a static ArrayList that i created & populated in MainActivity.
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    adapter = new Adapter(arr, this);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**My Adapter class:**

```java
public Adapter(ArrayList<Emote> arr, CommonMethods commonMethodsInterface) {
    this.emoteArray = new ArrayList<>(arr); //here is where it crashes.
    this.emoteArrayFull = new ArrayList<>(arr);

    this.commonMethodsInterface = commonMethodsInterface;
}
```

**in my MainActivity i create my ArrayList like this ( it contains about 100 items):**

```java
myArray.add(new Emote("name",R.raw.soundFile,R.drawable.icon,"type","rarity"));
```

Comment: What type is `emoteArray`?

Comment: @Shantanu custom object ( Emote)

Comment: post how you create `arr`

Comment: debug on this line, and check if `arr` is null

Comment: @Shantanu as i mentioned i never got the error my self. I tried almost all emulators with different api levels & all android devices i own and yet the app works perfectly on all. The error log is coming from google play console and i get it reported everyday

Comment: @a_local_nobody i did.

Comment: The error is NullPointerException so there is an error. Try to do a `try {} catch{}` before that line

Comment: have you tried adding `myArray = new ArrayList<Emote>();` before `myArray.add(new Emote("name",R.raw.soundFile,R.drawable.icon,"type","rarity"));`?

Comment: @DarShan yes its already there. Im getting the error in the adapter class not MainActivity.

Comment: @Ibrahim you can try initializing the `emoteArray = new ArrayList<Emote>()` at class level and then use `emoteArray.addAll(arr);` in the Adapter Constructor